# How can I modify the appearance of Melon vines?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've been playing Minecraft with a texture mod lately - I like it over "classic" minecraft on many levels, but I find there's still aspects of it that bug me, like this:

[image]

The sprouts of melon seeds are invisible.
(Here's a comparison with the default textures)
[image]

Where, exactly, are the various stages of melon growth stored? Or, if there's not multiple textures for melon sprouts, how does Minecraft go from the seed-like stage to the fully grown texture? Is it just a matter of making the melon sprout textures taller?

Comment: @Rudolf Libel nodded Minecraft does immediately seen a question off topic. Only technical support is considered off topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Technical_blocks#Melon_Stem), the texture is offset underground then extended up as the melon (or pumpkin) stem grows. It's just a matter of making sure the stem texture is tall enough.

Comment: Excellent! Your link pointed to Pumpkins, but melons were directly below that on the page, so it worked out all right in the end.